# Why does std::list::front result change after creating a new list?

Tags: c++

In the following code, why does `list_front` change after calling `gen_list` a second time? `gen_list` is creating a new list, how does that change a previous list head?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

std::list<int> gen_list()
{
    static int s_count = 0;
    std::list<int> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        result.push_back(s_count++);
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const auto& list_front = gen_list().front();
    std::cout<<list_front<<"\n";
    gen_list();
    std::cout<<list_front<<"\n";
}
```

result:

```
0
9
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EUwgaZ)

Comment: You have UB. `const auto& list_front = gen_list().front();`, the object is destroyed right after this line. Remove the reference.

Comment: @ChrisMM Shouldn't const refs extend rvalues lifetime?

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. Instead, I get "2" printed out twice.

Comment: @Epic A reference can extend the lifetime of a temporary. But `gen_list().front()` is not a temporary (it's an lvalue). (The list returned by `gen_list()` is a temporary, but you are not binding any reference to it.)

Comment: This section details the lifetime of a temporary object
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary

Comment: `&list_front` remains same in both cases and value changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind to the temporary `std::list<int>` returned by `gen_list()`:

```
const auto& list = gen_list();
const auto& list_front = list.front();
```

otherwise, the `std::list<int>` will be destroyed at the end of the expression and you'll have a dangling reference. Any use of the dangling reference makes your program have undefined behavior.

Comment: Why does that dangling reference prints out value of `s_count` everytime?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`front()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/front) returns a `reference`.

You commented: *const refs extend rvalues' lifetime*, but `front()` doesn't provide a rvalue.  Here, you have something you can assign to, i.e. an *lvalue*, so you have actually a reference variable to part of a temporary object whose lifetime ends at the end of that statement.

So your code exhibits undefined behavior.

To extend lifetime of this variable, you need something which will extend lifetime of `list` - look at [Ted Lyngmo's answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/60619742).